# How to put a tab detached from fullscreen Safari back into it

Tags: macos, safari, mojave

- Start Safari
- full-screen Safari
- open at least 2 tabs
- click and drag one of them away from the tab bar
- release left-click
- it creates a new full-screen Safari instance, with that tab as the only tab

Now, how do I take that tab, and put it back into the other Safari window?

Comment: If you only have the one window which had two tabs and now is two full screen windows, you can do Safari > Window > Merge All Windows but that is only good in that scenario, otherwise you'd have to bring both windows out of full screen, add a new tab to one of the windows and then drag the other tab back to the other window, then close the window that you opened a new tab on.

Answer (score 3):

- Make two tabs in one window, other free tab can now be brought in.
- Window Menu > Merge all windows.